# maximum data size for socket data event listener

Tags: flash, sockets, actionscript-3

is there a limit to data size that a Flash socket can receive through the ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA event handler? Based on my tests it seems to be 64240 bytes, although I'm not sure since as of now I haven't seen any documentation about that

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure this depends on the TCP configuration, i.e. it would be the packet size of TCP, although, probably, it may "glue" together few packages, there's no definitive answer to your question :) It is surely less then maximum integer value though.

Why would you need that anyway? I mean, it would depend on the user's machine, so even if you can adjust it locally to achieve certain values, users need not have it set up the same way.

Comment: where can I actually set this (packet size of TCP)? because I'm just sending the packets to a localhost socket anyway, so I assume there would be no network restrictions there, so does that mean that whatever the size of the packet I send into the socket (using Java), I also receive that FULLY using Flash socket's ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA? I just cannot seem to receieve more than 64240 bytes per ProgressEvent

Comment: it is also stated that socket.bytesAvailable is "The number of bytes of data available for reading in the input buffer.", is there any way to set the size of this input buffer?

Comment: i tried setting the TcpWindowSize registry value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736.aspx) to about 256k+ but after restarting I'm still just able to get 65535 max per socket data event, I'm not sure but perhaps that the max value. Also tested in a Win7 machine and 65k seems to be the max

Comment: ok, so simply put perhaps there is really nothing good which can be done about this? As you have said "In Windows, afaik, this is a global setting somewhere in the registry. Again, I think that what you see is random / specific to your machine" and so this is really something based on the user's machine and even though you also said that "I wouldn't let users configure the setting", it appears that this is not something which can be controlled at all on the application's end which is sending and/or receiving the data, is that correct?